# Sockets and threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am having a small problem when trying to implement a client-server program with multithreading on the side of the server. My idea is to have the server spin forever, accept a client when it can, and just send it to a client_handle() function using a thread.

**Here is the problem:** my server and client are using the code seen below. At the point of the initial response of the server, it fails in sending `ALL_GOOD_CD`. I'm not sure why this is happening, as I print out the socket fd of the client in a line before and it seems to match up with the file descriptor given to us at the time of acception.

One thought is that my socket id is not being passed to the thread correctly. My client never seems to receive the ALL_GOOD_CD (it is blocking on a `recv()` call after connecting with the server). I am new with threads and sockets, anything would help; thanks!

Here is the client code needed to run:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), send(), and recv() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_addr() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);  /* Error handling function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;                           /* Socket descriptor */
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;     /* Server address */
    unsigned short server_port;         /* Server port */
    char *server_ip;                    /* Server IP address (dotted quad) */
    char server_response[300];   /* Buffer to hold response from the server */
    char* username;

    /* Test for correct number of arguments */
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <server_ip> <server_port> <username>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    server_ip = argv[1];            /* Second arg: server IP address (dotted quad) */
    server_port = atoi(argv[2]);    /* Third arg: server port number */
    username = argv[3];             /* Fourth arg: username */

    /* Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
        DieWithError("socket() failed");

    /* Construct the server address structure */
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));       /* Zero out structure */
    server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;              /* Internet address family */
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip); /* Server IP address */
    server_addr.sin_port        = htons(server_port);   /* Server port */

    /* Establish the connection to the server */
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
        DieWithError("connect() failed, could not find server.");

    printf("connected\n");

    memset(&server_response, 0, 300);
    if (recv(sock, server_response, 300, 0) < 0)
        DieWithError("recv() for initial response failed");

    printf("received initial reponse\n");
}

void DieWithError(char* errorMessage) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Dying with error sadface: %s\n", errorMessage);
    exit(1);
}
```

Here is the server code as minified as possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), send(), and recv() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_addr() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include <pthread.h>    /* multithreading the clients! */

#define MAXMSGSIZE 150
#define MAXCLIENTS 5
#define TOO_MANY_CD 0
#define ALL_GOOD_CD 1
#define OTHER_BAD_CD 2

struct client {
    char* username;
    char** subs;
    int socket;
    char temp_msg[MAXMSGSIZE*2];
};

void DieWithError(char* errorMessage);  /* Error handling function */
void handle_client(void* new_socket); /* Client handling function */

static struct client** clients;
static pthread_t* threads;
static pthread_mutex_t clients_mutex;
static pthread_mutex_t threads_mutex;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int server_sock;                /* Server socket descriptor */
    unsigned short server_port;     /* Echo server port */
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr; /* sockaddr_in struct to hold information about the server */
    int server_addr_size;           /* Size of server_addr struct in bytes */
    int client_sock;
    int empty_thread;
    pthread_attr_t thread_attr;

    if (argc != 2) {  /* Test for correct number of arguments */
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <server_port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    clients = (struct client**) calloc(1, sizeof(struct client*) * MAXCLIENTS);
    if (clients == NULL)
        DieWithError("calloc() for clients failed");
    threads = (pthread_t*) calloc(1, sizeof(pthread_t) * MAXCLIENTS);
    if (clients == NULL)
        DieWithError("calloc() for clients failed");

    pthread_mutex_init(&clients_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&threads_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    server_port = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP */
    if ((server_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
        DieWithError("socket() failed");

    // Zero out server_addr var and fill with information
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);

    // Bind server with sock, IP, and port so that the clients can connect to us
    if (bind(server_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
        DieWithError("bind() failed");

    // Allow this server to accept 5 clients at a time (queue has 0 capacity because we multithread)
    if (listen(server_sock, 0) < 0)
        DieWithError("listen() failed");

    // Display some information so we can connect with client
    printf("Using\n\tport: %d\n\tIP: %s\n", server_port, inet_ntoa(server_addr.sin_addr));
    server_addr_size = sizeof(server_addr);
  for (;;) {
    int* new_socket = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if ((*new_socket = accept(server_sock, 
        (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, &server_addr_size)) < 0) {
      printf("accept() failed");
      continue;
    }
    int free_spot = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++)
        if (!threads[i]) free_spot = i;
    if (free_spot == -1) {
        printf("no empty threads (max clients handled currently)");
        send(*new_socket,(void*) OTHER_BAD_CD, sizeof(OTHER_BAD_CD), 0);
        close(*new_socket);
        continue;
    }

    if (pthread_create(&threads[free_spot], &thread_attr,
        (void*) &handle_client, (void*) new_socket)) {
      printf("pthread_create failed");
      close(*new_socket);
      continue;
    }
    printf("sent new client %d to handle_client()\n", *new_socket);
  }
}

void handle_client(void* new_socket) {
    int socket = *(int*)new_socket;
    free(new_socket);
    printf("handling new client %d\n", socket);
    struct client* curr_cl;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);
    printf("locked mutex?\n");
    if (send(socket, (void*)ALL_GOOD_CD, sizeof(ALL_GOOD_CD), 0) < 0) {
        printf("inital all good resp failed");
        send(socket, (void*)OTHER_BAD_CD, sizeof(OTHER_BAD_CD), 0);
        return;
    }
    printf("sent stuff\n");
    int free_spot = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++)
        if (!clients[i]) free_spot = i;

    printf("filtered through clients and got free spot %d\n", free_spot);
    if (free_spot == -1) {
        printf("didn't find free spot :(\n");
        send(socket, (void*)TOO_MANY_CD, sizeof(TOO_MANY_CD), 0);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
        return;
    }
    printf("found free spot %d for client %d", free_spot, socket);
    clients[free_spot] = (struct client*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct client));
    if (clients[free_spot] == NULL) {
        send(socket, (void*)OTHER_BAD_CD, sizeof(OTHER_BAD_CD), 0);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
        return;
    }
    curr_cl = clients[free_spot];

    if (recv(socket, curr_cl->username, sizeof(curr_cl->username), 0) < 0) {
        send(socket, (void*)OTHER_BAD_CD, sizeof(OTHER_BAD_CD), 0);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
        return;
    }

    // Subscribe client to #ALL automatically
    curr_cl->subs[0] = "#ALL";

    if (send(socket, (void*)ALL_GOOD_CD, sizeof(ALL_GOOD_CD), 0) < 0) {
        printf("send() for final all good failed\n");
        send(socket, (void*)OTHER_BAD_CD, sizeof(OTHER_BAD_CD), 0);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
        return;
    }
    printf("\taccepted new client %s and now listening\n", curr_cl->username);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
    return;
}

void DieWithError(char* errorMessage) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Dying with error sadface: %s\n", errorMessage);
    exit(1);
}
```

Here is the Makefile

```
# the compiler: gcc for C
CC = gcc

# compiler flags
CFLAGS = -g

make: ttweetcl.c ttweetsrv.c
    gcc -o ttweetcli ttweetcl.c && gcc -o ttweetsrv ttweetsrv.c -lpthread

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f ./ttweetcli ./ttweetsrv
```

Comment: do you ever unlock `clients_mutex`? If `handle_client` is mostly going to operate as a critical section then using multiple threads isn't going to help much.

Comment: @yano I do I just didn't show it. `handle_client`'s only critical section is when it determines if we can hold the client. If we can, we finish setting up the connection and unlock `clients_mutex` before listening to what they have to say.

Comment: <O/T>, not a good use of `goto` IMO.. you can replace the first `goto begin;` with `continue;`, then get rid of `begin:` and the second `goto begin;` and have the same functionality.

Comment: your last `printf` is also missing a closing `"`, this won't compile. Providing an MCVE will elicit the most help. Perhaps `clients_mutex` is conditionally unlocked?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you expect us to do with this.  You seem to have omitted some of the parts most likely to be related to the problem.  Please, present a *bona fide* [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  Perhaps that wouldn't require much more than you've already presented.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I stated it; the code only executes up to a certain `printf()` statement. I modified the question a little bit to show this. If you can explain why this isn't an MCVE then I will be happy to modify my question. On the part of 'Verifiable' I don't see how this is possible without posting too much code.

Comment: If you want more details about what an MCVE is and how to produce one, then you will find them on the other side of the handy hyperlink that's right there in my previous comment.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added more code; is it now verifiable? I ran the exact same code on my machine and it produces an erring result. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! One comment (now removed) noticed that I was not ending my `printf()`'s with a `\n` and therefore was not flushing the buffer. Now that I have added all `\n`'s then the code executes as it should.